# failure configuring LB attributes: InvalidConfigurationRequest: Access Denied for bucket: lb-11. Please check S3bucket permission status code: 400, re

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am seeing following error when trying to create ALB,

```
**Error:** failure configuring LB attributes: InvalidConfigurationRequest: Access Denied for bucket: lb-11. Please check S3bucket permission
│       status code: 400, request id: 2940f342-8e1e-4d6b-b653-5aa5d231d4cf
```

I have followed aws documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/enable-access-logging.html

this github link https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/1956

and several other stackoverflow posts but nothing found that I am missing.

I have verified my bucket policy multiple times and everything looks correct but still I am seeing the above error. Now I am not sure what is wrong.

AWS document suggest following troubleshooting but all is ok,
**Troubleshooting**
If you receive an access denied error, the following are possible causes:

1. The bucket policy does not grant Elastic Load Balancing permission to write access logs to the bucket.
2. The bucket uses an unsupported server-side encryption option. The bucket must use Amazon S3-managed keys (SSE-S3).

region=eu-central-1

Here is my bucket policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::054676820928:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::lb-11/alb/AWSLogs/3583xxxxxx/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Encryption-key used:

[image]

`main.tf`

```
module "alb" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/alb/aws"
  version = "8.7.0"
#AWS LB Input Parameters
  name                  = var.name
  load_balancer_type    = var.load_balancer_type
  internal              = var.internal
  subnets               = var.alb_subnets
  idle_timeout          = var.idle_timeout
  enable_deletion_protection                  = var.enable_deletion_protection
  enable_http2                                = var.enable_http2
  ip_address_type                             = var.ip_address_type
  drop_invalid_header_fields                  = var.drop_invalid_header_fields
  access_logs           = var.access_logs
  tags                  = var.mandatory_tags
  lb_tags               = var.lb_tags
  target_groups         = var.target_groups
  vpc_id                = var.tefde_vpcId

#AWS LB Target Group Input Parameters
  target_group_tags     = var.lb_tags

#AWS LB Listener Rules Input Parameters
  https_listener_rules          = var.https_listener_rules
  http_tcp_listener_rules       = var.http_tcp_listener_rules
  https_listener_rules_tags     = var.lb_tags
  http_tcp_listener_rules_tags  = var.lb_tags

#AWS LB Listener Input Parameters
  http_tcp_listeners       = var.http_tcp_listeners
  http_tcp_listeners_tags  = var.lb_tags
  https_listeners          = var.https_listeners
  https_listeners_tags     = var.lb_tags

#AWS LB Security Group Input Parameters
  security_group_name           = var.security_group_name
  security_group_description    = var.security_group_description
  security_group_tags           = var.lb_tags
  security_group_rules          = var.security_group_rules
}
```

`terraform.tfvars`

```
##ALB##
name                            = "dev-LoadBalancer"
load_balancer_type              = "application"
internal                        = true
alb_subnets                     = ["subnet-00xxx", "subnet-05xxx"]
idle_timeout                    = 60
enable_deletion_protection      = true
enable_http2                    = true
ip_address_type                 = "ipv4"
drop_invalid_header_fields      = true
access_logs = {
  enabled = true
  bucket  = "lb-11"
  prefix  = "alb"
}
lb_tags = {
  applicationtype = "app"
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have to the question.

Comment: Hi @MarkoE, I have added the code. Have not pasted full tfvars content. Hope that is ok.

Comment: In the code above, I am using an existing bucket with right policy and encryption set. I did tried adding the s3 create bucket resource in the above same module as explained here, https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/elb_service_account.html but no luck.

Comment: Are the bucket and the ALB in the same region? Does the prefix `alb` already exist in the bucket?

Comment: Yes to both the questions. I even tried with a new bucket without prefix by removing prefix from the bucket policy and commenting it out in the code but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, not the full answer, but i ended up with:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
"arn:aws:iam::MY_ACCOUNT:role/TERRAFORM_ROLE",
"arn:aws:iam::MY_ACCOUNT:root" # optional
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::054676820928:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Also see https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/12010#issuecomment-1718718903

Answer (score 0):

for me that error is solved with changing the "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::0546xxxxxx28:root" i.e. elb-account-id = 0546xxxxxx28. we need to look for the elb-account-id from the documentation as: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/enable-access-logging.html#access-log-create-bucket >> Regions available before August 2022. there are the # AWS account for Elastic Load Balancing for your Region, change according to the region.